# ERROR - 400 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=[KEY]:Invalid argument. When I try to run tasks on Airflow (Google Composer)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Running my code on Composer, returns an ERROR when trying to create the bucket:

```
INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
INFO - Creating Bucket: tbf-processing-zone; Location: southamerica-east1; Storage Class: REGIONAL
[2022-01-14 14:05:39,048] {taskinstance.py:1152} ERROR - 400 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=[KEY]: Invalid argument.
```

My task code is:

```
        task_id='create_processing_bucket',
        bucket_name=PROCESSING_BUCKET_ZONE,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        storage_class='REGIONAL',
        location=LOCATION,
        labels={'team':'AirFlow(Composer)'},
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_storage_default"
    )
```

Am I missing something?
I will appreciate any help cause I'm trying since last night.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be for many reasons, but  you can check these:

1. **SDK Bug**

If you are using an SDK 2.20.0, it could be a [confirmed bug](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataflow.py#L47) in      the sdk.

You need to use the version 2.19.0 and it will work    correctly

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. **Airflow Connection**

You need to check the configuration of the airflow.You could see this    [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#airflow-1) about connection with airflow.

3. **API Request**

Validate the API request, see if the parameters you use in the [URL    are supported](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#typical). You could see this  [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1#objects) about API    reference.

**Edit**

You are using this [class](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/372849486cd455a4ff4821b01805a442f1a78417/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs.py)(line 92) in your code. This parameter `project_id=PROJECT_ID`, which is in your code. You don’t need to add this parameter. You can see this example.

```
CreateBucket = GoogleCloudStorageCreateBucketOperator(
    task_id="CreateNewBucket",
    bucket_name="test-bucket",
    storage_class="MULTI_REGIONAL",
    location="EU",
    labels={"env": "dev", "team": "airflow"},
    gcp_conn_id="airflow-conn-id",
)
```

The parameter `project_id=PROJECT_ID` only is added in the `template fields`. You can see this code.

```
  template_fields: Sequence[str] = (
        'bucket_name',
        'storage_class',
        'location',
        'project_id',
        'impersonation_chain',
    )
    ui_color = '#f0eee4'
```

Comment: I read the Airflow doc... I'll check the others. Thank you so far!

Comment: @Monni Did the answer help you?

Comment: Actually...we are not using SDK. we keep trying to fix this problem with the Airflow

Comment: @Monni Did you create the Json key and enter the local file path on the Airflow worker? like this "path /home/airflow/gcs/data/keyfile.json".

Comment: yes. we did it too...:(

Comment: Could be this parameter? I will remove and check. Thanks.

Comment: @Monni Did you have time to check?

Comment: I left the code with a friend for him to solve. but I think we'll give up using airflow for now.

Comment: we gave up using airflow, it wasn't working. Thanks for the help anyway.